# Bash Text file formatting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have some files with the following format:

```
555584280113;01-04-2013 00:00:11;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
552185022741;01-04-2013 00:00:13;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
5511965271852;01-04-2013 00:00:14;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
5511980644500;01-04-2013 00:00:22;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
553186398559;01-04-2013 00:00:31;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
555584280113;01-04-2013 00:00:41;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
558487839822;01-04-2013 00:01:09;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

I need to have them with a sequence of 10 digits long at the beginning, removed the prefix 55 on the second column (which I have done with a simple sed 's/^55//g') and reformat the date to look like this:

```
0000000001;555584280113;20130401 00:00:11;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000002;552185022741;20130401 00:00:13;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000003;5511965271852;20130401 00:00:14;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000004;5511980644500;20130401 00:00:22;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000005;553186398559;20130401 00:00:31;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000006;555584280113;01-04-2013 00:00:41;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

I have the date part in a separate way:

```
cat file.txt | cut -d\; -f2 | awk '{print $1}' |awk -v OFS="-" -F"-" '{print $3$2$1}'
```

And it works, but I don't know how to put all of them together, the sequence + sed for the prefix + change the date format. The sequence part I'm not even sure how to do it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`awk` is one of the **best** tool out there used for text parsing and formatting. Here is one way of meeting your requirements:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }
{
    printf "%010d;", NR
    $1 = substr($1,3)
    split($2, tmp, /[- ]/)
    $2=tmp[3]tmp[2]tmp[1]" "tmp[4]
}1' file
```

- We set the input and output field separator to `;`
- We use `printf` to format your first column number requirement
- We use `substr` function to remove the first two characters of column 1
- We use `split` function to format the time
- Using `1` we print rest of the statement as is.

**Output:**

```
0000000001;5584280113;20130401 00:00:11;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000002;2185022741;20130401 00:00:13;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000003;11965271852;20130401 00:00:14;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000004;11980644500;20130401 00:00:22;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000005;3186398559;20130401 00:00:31;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000006;5584280113;20130401 00:00:41;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000007;8487839822;20130401 00:01:09;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

Comment: This one worked perfect! Hats off. Thanks a lot. I will certainly read more about awk.

Answer (score 2):

If the name of the input file is `input`, then the following command removes the `55`, adds a 10-digit line number, and rearranges the date.  With GNU `sed`:

```
 nl -nrz -w10 -s\; input | sed -r 's/55//; s/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3\2\1/'
```

If one is using Mac OSX (or another OS without GNU `sed`), then a slight change is required:

```
 nl -nrz -w10 -s\; input | sed -E 's/55//; s/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3\2\1/'
```

Sample output:

```
0000000001;5584280113;20130401 00:00:11;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000002;2185022741;20130401 00:00:13;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000003;11965271852;20130401 00:00:14;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000004;11980644500;20130401 00:00:22;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000005;3186398559;20130401 00:00:31;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000006;5584280113;20130401 00:00:41;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
0000000007;8487839822;20130401 00:01:09;0,22;889;30008;1501;sms;/xxx/yyy/zzz
```

**How it works:**  `nl` is a handy *nix utility for adding line numbers.  `-w10` tells `nl` that we want 10 digit line numbers.  `-nrz` tells `nl` to pad the line numbers with zeros, and `-s\;` tells `nl` to add a semicolon after the line number.  (We have to escape the semicolon so that the shell ignores it.)

The remaining changes are handled by `sed`.  The `sed` command `s/55//` removes the first occurrence of `55`.  The rearrangement of the date is handled by `s/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3\2\1/`.

Comment: Not sure if it's my sed version but I got an error on this one: ➜  SMS_April_2013  nl -nrz -w10 -s\; SMS.txt | sed -r 's/55//; s/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/\3\2\1/'
sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: @Age That likely means that you are using a Mac.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use a Bash loop to do this.

```
i=0
while read f1 f2; do
    ((++i))
    IFS=\; read n d <<< $f1
    d=${d:6:4}${d:3:2}${d:0:2}
    printf "%010d;%d;%d %s\n" $i $n $d $f2
done < file.txt
```